# Difference between fetchrow_array and fetchall_arrayref when working with stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, perl, stored-procedures, dbi

I have recently used both to fetch result of a stored procedure. I have noticed that fetchrow_array returns the output of rows I select inside the stored procedure. Whereas fetchall_arrayref returns status of the stored procedure in the last row, along with selected rows in stored procedure.

Why we have this difference and is there a way to avoid getting the status of stored procedure inside fetchall_arrayref?

My stored Procedure

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[check_date_proc]
       @dateStart DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
       check_date
FROM
       date_Table

WHERE
       data_date = @dateStart
END;

GO
```

and i call it like this

```
exec check_date_proc '20160920';
```

fetchrow_array returns

```
20160920
```

fetchall_arrayref returns

```
20160920
0
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you give examples of what a query you're doing would look like, and of the output? It might help others google for a solution.

Comment: `fetchrow_array` only returns a single row (hence the name). What happens if you do `while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) { print "@row\n"; }`

Comment: i am doing `while (my @aData = $rQuery->fetchrow_array()) {
      print $rOutputHandler join(',',@aData)."\n";
    }`

Comment: Which database are you working with? Try fetching the rows as hashes (since the status of stored procedure is bound to come out with a different key than the column names of your rows).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which database type you are working with (and depending on the Perl DBD driver), it is likely that you are getting multiple result sets.

There is a way for processing multiple result sets (For ex., if you have executed two statements which have resulted in two result sets; and you want both of them).

Look [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01776.1604/doc/html/san1357754965430.html) for sample code.

Since, in your case, you want to ignore the status of the stored procedure, you may feel it convenient just to fetch the results as hashes (all rows in one pull OR each one one by one), and then use the names of the columns to get the data.